# Windows file permission blanked or corrupt

Tags: file-permissions

I have a file that was brought to my attention.
The user was complaining they weren't able to delete the file.

Upon further investigation it appears the permissions on the files are completely messed up. All other files in the directory are okay.

I am unable to even view the permissions, when I go to the Security tab I am presented with the message "You must have Read permissions to view...". I am logged in as an Administrator and I do not have this issue with other files.

I have tried

- Taking ownership of the file. I did this both as the local administrator account and as the system account (using psexec).
- File is not locked by another process.
- There are no warnings about the integrity of the file system, but I can't completely rule out file system corruption.
- The user appeared to have access right up until some time this morning. This is based on info gathered from our audit policy.
- From [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/293163/what-do-you-do-to-fix-corrupted-or-blocked-permissions-on-company-file-shares?rq=1) I managed to get a copy of fileacl and run it. But I received access denied messages.

  ```
  > fileacl "filename" /INHERIT /REPLACE /FORCE
  CreateFile failed, can't get file/dir attribute ! error! (rc=5)
  Access is denied.
  CreateFile error! (rc=5)
  Access is denied.
  Error in AddAccessRights for "file name"
  ```

  It's as if the permissions were blanked on the file. Which I don't understand because our users do not have the "Change permission" privilege on any files, even ones they own.

Are there any other tricks that can be done to regain permission to the file? Everything I have found is related to taking ownership, which I cannot do. Is there some other way of overriding the permissions on the file?

Comment: I had high hopes for another post I found on here actually http://serverfault.com/questions/293163/what-do-you-do-to-fix-corrupted-or-blocked-permissions-on-company-file-shares?rq=1. This didn't work either though.

Comment: Can you try running [cacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb490872.aspx) from an elevated command prompt, showing here the output?

Comment: When running cacls I received "Access is denied." when running from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Can you use [fileacl](http://am.net/lib/tools/AM/fileacl.2.8.0.3.htm) /force to regain access to the file?

Comment: I tried the following command fileacl.exe "filename" /INHERIT /REPLACE /FORCE. I received a bunch of Access Denied messages. I will update my post.